# why output is in scientific notation?

Tags: java, string, decimal, bigdecimal, scientific-notation

Why output of following code is in scientific notation?

```
      BigDecimal val = new BigDecimal("0000.000000111");
      System.out.println(val);
```

output: **1.11e-8**

but output of this code is proper in decimal format.

```
      BigDecimal val = new BigDecimal("0000.000011111");
      System.out.println(val);
```

output: **0.000011111**

Is there a way to get proper decimal value for first string(like second output)?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `BigDecimal.toString`?

Comment: Use `toPlainString()` to see BigDecimal representation without exponent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [the `toString()` function of BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString%28%29), it explains how the output is created:

> Next, an adjusted exponent is calculated; this is the negated scale,
>   plus the number of characters in the converted unscaled value, less
>   one. That is, -scale+(ulength-1), where ulength is the length of the
>   absolute value of the unscaled value in decimal digits (its
>   precision).
>
> If the scale is greater than or equal to zero and the adjusted
>   exponent is greater than or equal to -6, the number will be converted
>   to a character form without using exponential notation. In this case,
>   if the scale is zero then no decimal point is added and if the scale
>   is positive a decimal point will be inserted with the scale specifying
>   the number of characters to the right of the decimal point.

If you want the output without the `e10` notation, use [toPlainString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString()).

Answer (score 3):

use `toPlainString` method

```
BigDecimal val = new BigDecimal("0000.000011111");
          System.out.println(val.toPlainString());
```